# optimizing a logdet function with respect to a scalar and the Hessian matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Given a logdet function $\mathcal{L}(\gamma)$, 
$$
\mathcal{L}(\gamma) = \log\vert \mathbf{I} + \gamma\mathbf{S} \vert - \mathbf{q}^T(\gamma^{-1}\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{S})^{-1} \mathbf{q},
$$
where $\mathbf{S}$ is a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix, $\mathbf{q}$ is a column vector, and $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix.

Can I solve $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}(\gamma)}{\partial \gamma}=0$ in a closed form ? and how could I derive the Hessian $H = \frac{\partial^2 \mathcal{L}(\gamma)}{\partial \gamma^2}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the multivariate extension of the chain rule (some useful identities are on Wikipedia under "Matrix Calculus"), we can compute $\frac{\partial L(\gamma)}{\partial \gamma}$:

$$
\frac{\partial L(\gamma)}{\partial \gamma} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \gamma} \log|I + \gamma S| - \frac{\partial }{\partial \gamma}\left[q^T(\gamma^{-1}I+S)^{-1}q\right]\\
=tr((I+\gamma S)^{-1}S) -tr(qq^T\frac{\partial }{\partial \gamma}(\gamma^{-1}I+S)^{-1})\\
=tr(S^{-1/2}(S^{-1}+\gamma I)^{-1}S^{-1/2}S) + tr(qq^T(\gamma^{-1}I+S)^{-1}(-\gamma^{-2}I)(\gamma^{-1}I+S)^{-1}) \\
=tr((S^{-1}+\gamma I)^{-1})-\gamma^{-2}q^T(\gamma^{-1}I+S)^{-2}q\\
= \sum_i(\lambda_i^{-1}+\gamma)^{-1} - \gamma^{-2}q^T(\gamma^{-1}I+S)^{-2}q \\
= \sum_i(\lambda_i^{-1}+\gamma)^{-1} - q^T(I+\gamma S)^{-2}q
$$

where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $S$. Now, let the diagonalization of $S$ be given by $S = Q^{-1}\Sigma Q$. Then:

$$
= \sum_i(\lambda_i^{-1}+\gamma)^{-1} - q^T(I+\gamma Q^{-1}\Sigma Q)^{-2}q \\
= \sum_i(\lambda_i^{-1}+\gamma)^{-1} - tr(qq^T(I+\gamma Q^{-1}\Sigma Q)^{-2}) \\
= \sum_i(\lambda_i^{-1}+\gamma)^{-1} - tr(qq^TQ^{-2}(I+\gamma \Sigma )^{-2}Q^2) \\
= \sum_i(\lambda_i^{-1}+\gamma)^{-1} - tr(Q^2qq^TQ^{-2}(I+\gamma \Sigma )^{-2}) \\
= \sum_i(\lambda_i^{-1}+\gamma)^{-1} - \sum_i \dfrac{Z_{ii}}{(1+\gamma\lambda_i)^2}
$$
where $Z_{ii}$ are the diagonal entries of $Q^2qq^TQ^{-2}$. Set to zero and put in a more readable form, we have

$$
\sum_i \dfrac{Z_{ii}}{(1+\gamma\lambda_i)^2} = \sum_i \dfrac{\lambda_i}{1+\gamma\lambda_i}\\
\sum_i \dfrac{\lambda_i(1+\gamma\lambda_i) - Z_{ii}}{(1+\gamma\lambda_i)^2} = 0
$$

EDIT: Assuming the above calculations are correct, we can compute the Hessian.

$$
\frac{\partial^2 L(\gamma)}{\partial \gamma^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \gamma} 
\left[\sum_i(\lambda_i^{-1}+\gamma)^{-1} - q^T(I+\gamma S)^{-2}q \right]\\
=\sum_i-(\lambda_i^{-1}+\gamma)^{-2} - \frac{\partial}{\partial \gamma} q^T(I+\gamma S)^{-2}q\\
=\sum_i-(\lambda_i^{-1}+\gamma)^{-2} - tr(\frac{\partial}{\partial U(\gamma)} q^TU(\gamma)q \frac{\partial}{\partial \gamma}(I+\gamma S)^{-2})\\
=\sum_i-(\lambda_i^{-1}+\gamma)^{-2} - tr(qq^T \frac{\partial}{\partial \gamma}(I+\gamma S)^{-2}) \\
=\sum_i-(\lambda_i^{-1}+\gamma)^{-2} - tr(qq^T (I+\gamma S)^{-1}((I+\gamma S)^{-1}S + S(I+\gamma S)^{-1})(I+\gamma S)^{-1})
$$

The final steps comes from careful application of chain and product rules.

If we don't want the eigenvalue part, we can get
$$
=-tr((S^{-1}+\gamma I)^{-2}) - tr(qq^T (I+\gamma S)^{-1}((I+\gamma S)^{-1}S + S(I+\gamma S)^{-1})(I+\gamma S)^{-1})
$$

Comment: yes, in getting the closed-form of $\gamma$, we need to solve a trace equality, which writes, $tr[(I + \gamma S)^{-1}(S + \gamma SS - qq^T)(I + \gamma S)^{-1}]=0$. I think this type of equation is hard to solve, not only to say deriving the Hessian.

Comment: Yes, the solution is not immediately obvious, though I think calculating the Hessian should be tedious but not too hard. I will add it in a bit.

Comment: and any hint to approximate the $(\mathbf{I} + \gamma\mathbf{S})^{-1}$ ? If it can be approximate in a linear form, then may be we can solve the trace equality.

Comment: If $\gamma S$ is small (eigenvalues have absolute value less than $1$), then by Taylor expansion the first-order approximation would be $I - \gamma S$.

Comment: I reduced the equation from the trace equation, hope that helps.

Comment: There is a sign error, where $Z_{ii}$ should be $-Z_{ii}$. And I think it is quite close, given that $\gamma$ is non-negative and $\mathbf{S}$ is positive semidefinite, we have $(1 + \gamma\lambda_i)^2 \neq 0$ and therefore, we may only aim at the denominator, $(\lambda_i + \gamma\lambda_i^2 - Z_{ii})$.

Comment: **If** we  could let $const = (1+\gamma\lambda_i)^2$, then we can solve $\gamma$ in a closed-form, where $\gamma = \frac{1}{N}\sum_i \lambda_i^{-1}(Z_{ii} - \lambda_i)\lambda_i^{-1}$. and we may have $\gamma = \frac{1}{N}Tr(S^{-1}qq^TS^{-1} - S^{-1})$.

Comment: Where is the sign error?

Comment: the minus sign at the third line of your equation, where $d (\gamma^{-1}I + S)^{-1} = -(\gamma^{-1}I + S)^{-1}\frac{-1}{\gamma^2}(\gamma^{-1}I + S)^{-1} d\gamma_i = (\gamma^{-1}I + S)^{-1}\frac{1}{\gamma^2}(\gamma^{-1}I + S)^{-1} d\gamma_i$.